# Map value is a pointer to an abstract class

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, stl, abstract-class

I have an abstract class: `class Abstract_class {..};`

And an object from derived class: `Derived_class Ob;`

As well: `string name;` `map<string,Abstract_class*>mp;`

How to do something like this: `mp[name]=&Ob;` correctly?

Edit : This is an example

```
Abstract_class {..};

int main(){

    map<string,Abstract_class*>mp;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        int a,b,c; cin>>a>>b>>c;
        Derived_class Ob(a,b,c);
        string name; cin>>name;
        mp[name]=&Ob;
    }

    string s; cin>>s;
    Abstract_class* ptr=mp[s];
    ptr->Print(); // segmentation fault (core dumped)
    //Note: Print() is virtual function.
}
```

Comment: what exactly does not work?

Comment: Just asking if it's correct or not? I don't have any compilation error, but there is "segmentation fault (core dumped)" while calling any pure virtual function like this:
Abstract_class* ptr=mp["...."];
ptr->func( );

Comment: please post a minimal complete example (a 1-file, 10-line program we can compile) to exhibit the error

Comment: Remember if `Abstract_Class` and `Derived_Class` implement the same function, it must be `virtual` in `Abstract_Class`.

Comment: @RichardHodges Unfortunately, there is 10 files, each one include about 50-100 lines in my project.

Comment: @JackDeeth Of course I did.

Comment: @Abdulkader I didn't say copy your program here. I said you should post a tiny program that exhibits the specific behaviour you're talking about. Please follow this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My educated guess would be: you create `Ob` as a local variable on the stack, then put its address into a longer-lived map. When the function returns, `Ob` is destroyed and the map is left holding a dangling pointer. Any attempt to use said pointer then exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Exactly that is what I did. So, could you help me to solve this issue please?

Comment: Well, you need to ensure that the object remains alive for at least as long as the map holds its address. One way to achieve that would be to allocate it on the heap.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry, I did not understand how to allocate it on the heap. If you give me an example with explanation, I will be thankful.
Note: I do mp[name]=&Ob; in for loop.

Comment: As @RichardHodges suggests, rather than describing your code in prose, prepare and show [an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You now want me to give you suggestions taking into account the details of your code - the code that I can't see. There's only so much help one can provide blind.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I am sorry, I wrote an example.

Comment: `map<string, std::unique_ptr<Abstract_class>> mp;` and then `mp[name]=std::make_unique<Derived_class>(a, b, c);` [Demo](http://rextester.com/VWLB12006)

Comment: A piece of advice for asking in the future - give both the code (which you have done) and what specifically is going wrong (which you haven't). That way, someone reading the question can work backwards from the error.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Great, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in your code is right here:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int a,b,c; cin>>a>>b>>c;
    Derived_class Ob(a,b,c); // Oops!
    string name; cin>>name;
    mp[name]=&Ob;
}
```

You've declared `Derived_class` as a local variable inside of this for loop. That means that the object `Ob` only lives as long as the current for loop iteration is running. As soon as the loop iteration ends, `Ob`'s lifetime ends, the object ceases to exist, and you now have a pointer in your map that points to a dead object. That's not good!

To fix this, dynamically allocate the object:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    int a,b,c; cin>>a>>b>>c;
    Derived_class* Ob = new Derived_class(a,b,c); // Yay!
    string name; cin>>name;
    mp[name]=Ob;
}
```

The good news is that this issue has nothing to do with polymorphism or abstract classes or anything like that. It's just a plain and simple pointer issue.

To prevent memory leaks, you may want to consider using a map whose value type is something like a `shared_ptr<Abstract_class>` or `unique_ptr<Abstract_class>` rather than an `Abstract_class*`. That will automatically clean up the memory for you.

Comment: It is work now, thank you.

Comment: Did you mean that the call ptr->Print() Is not considered as Polymorphism (after your answer) :( ?

Comment: Without seeing more code I can't say for sure. Consider posting another question if you're curious!